# Mac Monterey "Live Text" Not Working for Imported Screenshots in Photos app

Tags: macos, photos, ocr, live-text

Live Text seems to work in Photos for pictures that I've taken with my iPhone camera.

However, I want to use the Live Text on screenshots from meetings.  I've imported the screenshot into Photos, with very clear text, but it only wants to treat it as pixels.  I can't share the text.  Some of it is a bit small, but very clear.

On this Mac, I do not have it automatically putting screen shots into photos; I only do that manually for particular screenshots.

I'm on an Intel iMac Pro (Intel Macs *do* now support Live Text; early reports that you need an M1 Mac are out of date), with up-to-date Monterey macOS.

Comment: I did try adjusting the image: changing contrast to just black and white, so no gray background.  And I used the Sharpness tool.  Other screenshots (from my iPhone) with much less text seem to work OK.  It's hard to believe it's a size limitation because the text is VERY clear.

Comment: If in the Preview app, if I copy and past the URL from the screenshot, then do File / New from Clipboard, then THAT small image does seem to have Live Text.  So I guess it's the amount of text in the image, but that still seems really odd.  This was a screenshot of an internal wiki page (but I can't share)

Comment: I just tried this on images I imported and live text works fine.  I can copy paste text off of handwritten words, too.  I'm on an M1 MBP with macOS 12.1.

Comment: Hi @fsb may I ask how much text was in the image?  Like maybe an ENTIRE Powerpoint with only 12 font, plus web address, does it still work with a LOT of text on the page?  (and THANKS for the comment)